# how to remove label from bar in bar graph

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, bar-chart

[image]

This code draws me a bar chart. y axis represents me a accuracy percentage. For each bar, the corresponding percentage(y axis) is put in the top of bar. I need to remove labels from bars in bar graph. Can you please help me?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
      \centering
      \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      title={Agreement Rate on Adult Salary Attribute},
      height=8cm, width=12cm,
      bar width=0.4cm,
      ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
      major grid style={draw=white},
      enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
      ymin=0, ymax=100,
      y axis line style={opacity=1},
      tickwidth=0pt,
      enlarge x limits=true,
      legend style={
          at={(0.5,-0.2)},
          anchor=north,
          legend columns=-1,
          /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
      },
      ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
      symbolic x coords={
          0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,
          0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,1.0},
      xtick=data,
      xlabel={Privacy Budget},
      nodes near coords={
          \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
      \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
          (0.15, 71.2)
          (0.2, 47.7)
          (0.25, 59.5)
          (0.3, 28.8)
          (0.4, 31.4)
          (0.5, 61.7)
          (0.6, 82.6)
          (0.8, 69.1)
          (1.0, 63.9)
      };
      \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which labels do you mean. Do you mean axis labels or xtick?

Comment: I have added picture to show labels more obvious. Please check it.

Comment: Remove `nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}`. It would be nice if you add always  a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))[please keep in mind in future], that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: is the question still open? Please let us know what is missing in the given answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}`.

Because you don't like: `nodes near coords`, which labels the coordinates, `\pgfmathprintnumber` applies all formating options (like `[precision=0]` ...)  and  `\pgfplotspointmeta` contains the y value of the ybar plot.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepgflibrary{curvilinear}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\tikzset{arrownode/.style={
    shape=single arrow,
    single arrow head extend=.75em,
    single arrow head indent=.25em,
    minimum width=3em,
    draw,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
      \centering
      \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      title={Agreement Rate on Adult Salary Attribute},
      height=8cm, width=12cm,
      bar width=0.4cm,
      ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
      major grid style={draw=white},
      enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
      ymin=0, ymax=100,
      y axis line style={opacity=1},
      tickwidth=0pt,
      enlarge x limits=true,
      legend style={
          at={(0.5,-0.2)},
          anchor=north,
          legend columns=-1,
          /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
      },
      ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
      symbolic x coords={
          0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,
          0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,1.0},
      xtick=data,
      xlabel={Privacy Budget},
      %nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
      ]
      \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
          (0.15, 71.2)
          (0.2, 47.7)
          (0.25, 59.5)
          (0.3, 28.8)
          (0.4, 31.4)
          (0.5, 61.7)
          (0.6, 82.6)
          (0.8, 69.1)
          (1.0, 63.9)
      };
      \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```